# Installing cuda-toolkit on ubuntu 15.10 hash sum mismatch

Tags: apt, nvidia, software-installation, cuda

I am trying to install cuda-toolkit to my fresh ubuntu-15.10 .
After reading the official instructions here `http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf`

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] (rev a1)

uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"

     gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

I downloaded the `cuda-repo-ubuntu1504-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb` file and run the following commands:

Installation Instructions:

`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1504-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install cuda`

But when I try installing cuda I get that message

```
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-7-5-local/./cuda-visual-tools-7-5_7.5-18_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried `apt-get update` and everything updated correctly.
With `--fix-missing?` I get

```
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-7-5-local/./cuda-visual-tools-7-5_7.5-18_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Aborting install.
```

Nvidia drivers under additional drivers section

```
Using NVIDIA binary driver-version 340.96 from nvidia-340(proprietary,tested)
```

If anyone has anything to suggest or if I did something wrong please help me I am new to Ubuntu as well to cuda .
Thank you very much.